# Showing Up of Product Options on Products List

Tags: x-cart

how to show **product options on product list** in **xcart 4.4.2**.Under the Men's Clothes category, in shirts, I need to show options like color,size on shirts list itself.Now currently it is in **shirt details** page.Can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution. This will display all options values for each products in categories specified by category IDs in array(246, 247) in the condition. You should replace it with your own category IDs (home.php?cat=XXX, XXX - it's a category ID)

Patch for products.php

```
@@ -133,6 +133,14 @@

 }

+if (isset($cat) && in_array($cat, array(246, 247)) && isset($products) && !empty($active_modules['Product_Options'])) {
+    foreach ($products as $k => $v) {
+        if ('Y' == $v['is_product_options']) {
+            $products[$k]['options'] = func_get_product_classes($v['productid']);
+        }
+    }
+}
+
 $smarty->assign('cat_products',      isset($products) ? $products : array());
 $smarty->assign('navigation_script', "home.php?cat=$cat&sort=$sort&sort_direction=$sort_direction");
 ?>
```

Patch for skin/common_files/customer/main/products_list.tpl

```
@@ -45,6 +45,10 @@

         <div class="descr">{$product.descr}</div>

+          {if $active_modules.Product_Options ne ""}
+            {include file="modules/Product_Options/show_options.tpl" product_options=$product.options}
+          {/if}
+
         {if $product.rating_data}
           {include file="modules/Customer_Reviews/vote_bar.tpl" rating=$product.rating_data productid=$product.productid}
         {/if}
```

skin/common_files/modules/Product_Options/show_options.tpl

```
{if $product_options ne ''}
<br />
  {foreach from=$product_options item=v}
    {if $v.options ne ''}
       {$v.class|escape}:
       {foreach from=$v.options item=o}
           {$o.option_name|escape},
       {/foreach}
    {/if}
  <br />
  {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Comment: It works thanks for ur reply...But when I select an options in it and I add a product to cart means,it will not show options I selected...showing only default options...Do u have any idea to correct it??Thanks in Advance....

Comment: In your question you asked about 'how to show product options', not how to select options and add to cart with selected options. If you need it you shoud replace static text with select/input boxes for each option class (use template skin/common_files/modules/Product_Options/customer_options.tpl as an example) and move call of this template from skin/common_files/customer/main/products_list.tpl to skin/common/customer/main/buy_now.tpl under the form tag.

Comment: The site shows I need 15 Reputation to vote.Currently I have only one reputation....